# How to read a file with a semi colon separator in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I a importing a `.csv` file in python with pandas.

Here is the file format from the `.csv` :

```
a1;b1;c1;d1;e1;...
a2;b2;c2;d2;e2;...   
.....
```

here is how  get it :

```
from pandas import *
csv_path = "C:...."
data = read_csv(csv_path)
```

Now when I print the file I get that :

```
0  a1;b1;c1;d1;e1;...
1  a2;b2;c2;d2;e2;...
```

And so on... So I need help to read the file and split the values in columns, with the semi color character `;`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) takes a `sep` param, in your case just pass `sep=';'` like so:

```
data = read_csv(csv_path, sep=';')
```

The reason it failed in your case is that the default value is `','` so it scrunched up all the columns as a single column entry.

Comment: Is there a way to programatically tell if a CSV is separated by `,` or `;` ?

Comment: @Morris: You can tell pandas to infer which delimiter to use by passing `sep=None`, if that is what you mean. Pandas uses the python standard library [csv.Sniffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) to do this.

Answer (score 7):

In response to Morris' question above:
"Is there a way to programatically tell if a CSV is separated by , or ; ?"

This will tell you:

```
import pandas as pd

df_comma = pd.read_csv(your_csv_file_path, nrows=1,sep=",")
df_semi = pd.read_csv(your_csv_file_path, nrows=1, sep=";")
if df_comma.shape[1]>df_semi.shape[1]:
    print("comma delimited")
else:
    print("semicolon delimited")
```