# Splitting a CSV into separate columns by the semicolons

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have to train an algorithm for assessment of the wines using a provided dataset. However, the dataset has all the data clumped together in 1 column (separated by semicolons) and I am unsure on how to go about splitting them.

This is the output of the data the way it is currently formatted:
[image: This is the output of the data the way it is currently formatted]
I have tried the code below and a couple other things, but it puts them all in an array, which I want to be working with a table/ dataframe:

```
df2 = []

with open('winequality-white.csv', 'r') as reading:
    file_input = reading.read().split('\n')

for row in file_input:
    df2.append(row.split(';'))

print(df2)
```

Why does this not work and how should I go about splitting it?

Comment: You can directly use read_csv with sep argument, df = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', sep = ';')

Comment: use pandas read in options "delimiter=" and specify the correct separator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file with a semi colon separator in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and pass a semicolon to the `sep` parameter. Try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')
```