# Column not read from semicolon separated CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Why i cant access to these columns of a csv?
CSV is not UTF-8 encoded.

```
df_sii = pd.read_csv('78610880-2_25102019_27102019.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')
df_sii.columns

Index(['Linea;Rut Emisor;Razon Social;Tipo Dte;Folio Dte;Fecha Emision(DD-MM-AAAA);Monto Total;Fecha Hora Recepcion(DD-MM-AAAA HH:MM);TrackId'], dtype='object')
```

When I wanna access to a column give me the below error:

```
df_sii['Rut Emisor']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

KeyError: 'Rut Emisor'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-bbef2f6b58b7> in <module>
----> 1 df_sii['Rut Emisor']

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

KeyError: 'Rut Emisor'
```

This is the Dataframe with ; delimiters:

```
    Linea;Rut Emisor;Razon Social;Tipo Dte;Folio Dte;Fecha Emision(DD-MM-AAAA);Monto Total;Fecha Hora Recepcion(DD-MM-AAAA HH:MM);TrackId
0   1;76961029-4;XANDOCORP TECNOLOGIA SPA;Factura Electronica;212;2019-10-27;99502;2019-10-27 23:26;4096898400
1   2;76961029-4;XANDOCORP TECNOLOGIA SPA;Factura Electronica;211;2019-10-27;9549821;2019-10-27 23:23;4096897508
2   3;76961029-4;XANDOCORP TECNOLOGIA SPA;Factura Electronica;210;2019-10-27;1739304;2019-10-27 23:19;4096896436
3   4;76961029-4;XANDOCORP TECNOLOGIA SPA;Factura Electronica;209;2019-10-27;63801;2019-10-27 23:14;4096894748
4   5;76861791-0;SOCIEDAD S Y M LOGISTICS SPA;Factura Electronica;109;2019-10-27;1212848;2019-10-27 23:10;4096893402
5   6;76868307-7;SERVIEXTERNOS SPA;Factura Electronica;78;2019-10-27;143659;2019-10-27 23:00;4096890316
6   7;96870370-6;ACCOR CHILE S. A.;Nota de Credito Electronica;16001;2019-10-27;128011;2019-10-27 14:47;4096609484
7   8;96870370-6;ACCOR CHILE S. A.;Factura Electronica;175748;2019-10-27;128011;2019-10-27 14:45;4096606476
8   9;76314405-4;PRODUCTORA GRÁFICA Y CIA. LIMITADA;Factura Electronica;805;2019-10-27;2153900;2019-10-27 13:39;4096579244
9   10;96870370-6;ACCOR CHILE S. A.;Factura Electronica;175746;2019-10-27;110810;2019-10-27 12:23;4096538192
10  11;96870370-6;ACCOR CHILE S. A.;Factura Electronica;175743;2019-10-27;349727;2019-10-27 09:22;4096464302
11  12;96870370-6;ACCOR CHILE S. A.;Factura Electronica;175742;2019-10-27;171266;2019-10-27 08:29;4096450914
```

Comment: Paste the data from the CSV, not the dataframe.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Can u see now? when I output the df_iss, give me the below data how can i separate?

Comment: `df_sii = pd.read_csv('78610880-2_25102019_27102019.csv', sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1')`.  The actual question seems to be how to read in a `;` separated `csv`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to read a file with a semi colon separator in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas)

Comment: thank u so much for the answer! work for me