# Format problem: pandas df.values.tolist() is converting rows into lists but lists each have just one item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, tolist

Table with 4 Columns and 10 Rows. Reading in as dataframe(df).

Then from there using lists = `df.values.tolist()` produces
print(lists)

Outcome:

```
[['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0'], ['30;30;30;0']]
```

Problem: Why are the values separated by semicolon instead of a comma. Each list has then just one value. :/  I followed exactly the documentation.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Smells like a CVS with `;` as separator read into software expecting commas as separator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed first my european standard delimiter, that was not helping even after making a new `csv` file and loading it up into python.

It is much easier solvable by just:
adding in the pandas read:

```
data = read_csv(csv_path, **sep=';')**
```

Thanks [Joanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis) for the hint.

here to find:
[How to read a file with a semi colon separator in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas)