# How to delete multiple rows of a .csv file in jupyter notebook using Python?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, delete-row

Hi so I am very new to coding!
I have a huge .csv file (over 1 million rows) and need to delete all data that is before 1st January 2010 at 00:00.

Have tried googling how to do this but can't seem to find anything that doesn't use row numbers, rather than deleting by the date/time.

I tried:

```
df [(df['Date Time'].dt.year < 2010-0o1)]
```

But it came up with a very long error (have screenshotted most of that in the image below:

[image: error message]

edit: i have also included a snippet of what the file looks like with the headings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb0Oh.jpg)

Comment: Please could you include a snippet of your df. say df.head(5) so we can see the type of data and the column headings? It looks like you do not have a 'Date Time' column but the code is may still not run with this corrected

Comment: ah yes sorry! just edited the post to show that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file is semi-colon separated rather than comma seperated and so has read all columns as a single heading.

Try `df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')`

Similar discussion here:
[How to read a file with a semi colon separator in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas)