# I need to find peaks in the data of the y-Gforce difference

Tags: python, arrays, csv, histogram, keyerror

**I need a python script that finds the peaks of each period in a csv file wih the following format:**

| time | gFx | gFy | gFz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0,0039 | 0,0005 | 0,0008 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8 | 0,0052 | 0,0015 | -0,0002 |

the values represented by the three dots are forces that vary from aprox. 0,0050 to -0,0050 over a time of 8 seconds.

I need to first of all change the numbers in the gFy column from 0,0050 to 0.0050 but it doesnt work. Please help me out.

I tried to get the column gFy and replace the `','` with `'.'` but i get a Key error:
`KeyError: 'gFy'`

this would mean the gFy column is non existend but when i tried to print all column names it appears to be the right column.

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read CSV file and split column names by semicolon
df = pd.read_csv('G-forceData.csv', sep='\t')
print(df.columns.values) # used this to see the correct key value of the gFy column

# Convert gFy column to a numpy array of float
gFy = np.array(df['gFy'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float))

# Print the array
print(gFy)


peaks, _ = np.histogram(gFy, bins=50)
peak_indices = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(peaks))) == -2)[0] + 1
```

Comment: What does `print(df.columns.values)` print?

Comment: It gives me the column names: ['time;gFx;gFy;gFz']

Comment: That isn't 4 column names. It's one column name of `time;gFx;gFy;gFz`. The delimiter is incorrectly set. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas