# Cannot read column in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

When I'm trying to do this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv")
df.head()
```

```
And the results are:
0       2018-01-01;100
1   2018-01-02;97
2   2018-01-03;65
3   2018-01-04;55
4   2018-01-05;33
```

The results doesnt show up in column format (Datas are not detected).
What should I do to make datas are detected?
I'm new in Python

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606330/how-to-read-a-file-with-a-semi-colon-separator-in-pandas ?

Comment: add `sep=';'` ...

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to your "name.csv" being a semicolon-separated file, instead of the usual comma-separated. Pandas.read_csv defaults to reading files that are comma-separated (see also: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). To change this, do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("name.csv", sep=';')
df.head()
```